# Using puts.chomp after reading a File object on Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a Call Detail Record (CDR) parser on Ruby. CDRs are files with lines, where every line is an action, and the fields of these lines are separated by tabs.

My problem happens after reading every line of the file using CDRFileParser. When I'm using `gets.chomp` to get some interactivity with the user, `gets.chomp` won't wait until I press enter, instead it starts using the lines from the file that was already closed. It seems to be a IO buffer problem. (In C I use `fflush()` for this kind of issue.)

The files of my program are:

command_line_loader.rb:

```
def comm_line_loader
  begin
    raise ArgumentError, 'Invalid number of arguments' unless ARGV.length == 1
    return File.new(ARGV[0],"r")
  rescue ArgumentError
    warn "Debe ingresar el nombre del archivo que contiene los CDR"
    exit
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    warn "El archivo no existe o hay un error en su lectura"
    exit
  end
end
```

objects.rb:

```
class CDRFileParser
  def initialize(cdr_source)
    @cdr_source = cdr_source
    @cdr_list = cdr_to_array
  end
  def cdr_to_array
    cdr_list_aux = Array.new
    cdr_list_aux.push @cdr_source.readline.split("\t") unless @cdr_source.eof?
    return cdr_list_aux
  end
  attr_accessor :cdr_list
end
```

cdr_parser.rb (useless program that shows the problem):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "./command_line_loader"
require "./objects"
cdr = CDRFileParser.new (comm_line_loader)
loop do
  a = gets.chomp
  puts a
end
```

Your help and coding suggestions will be really appreciated :)

Comment: How is `puts.chomp` relevant to your question?

Comment: There is no point wrapping *the file reading* in a method.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
Sawa, the gets.chomp is relevant given that i need some interactivity with the user. 
Windor C, i will take your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Kernel#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) method only reads from standard input if `ARGV` is empty. Try using `$stdin.gets.chomp` instead. Alternatively, clear `ARGV` after you are done reading from it with `ARGV.clear` and `gets` will work as you expect.

Comment: Both solutions (use $stdin.gets.chomp and ARGV.clear) worked very well. Thank you very much for the help.